# Count the labels value and use it in another query - PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-variable

I'm making a Grafana dashboard to display the performance of the canary application. My problem is I need to find out which instance is the canary one (blue or green).

Canary stack will always create one instance either blue or green so  I can see the count of the instance using the below query but can't make to display the value of the bound metric.

**(count(bound(cfstack=".*Blue.*")) == 1) or ( count(bound(cfstack=".*Green.*")) == 1**)

How can I express the following in PromQL?

```
if ( count(bound(cfstack=".*Blue.*")) == 1 )
   cfstack_val=".*Blue.*"
else 
  if ( count(bound(cfstack=".*Green.*")) == 1 )
    cfstack_val=".*Green.*"

bound(cfstack="${cfstack_val}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
(bound{cfstack=~".*Blue.*"} and on() (count(bound{cfstack=~".*Blue.*"}) == 1))
  or
(bound{cfstack=~".*Green.*"} and on() (count(bound{cfstack=~".*Green.*"}) == 1))
```

This query works in the following way:

1. It selects a time series matching the `bound{cfstack=~".*Blue.*"}` only if there is only a single such a time series.
2. It selects a time series matching the `bound{cfstack=~".*Green.*"}` only if there is only a single such a time series.
3. It returns both results from steps 1 and 2 with the help of `or` operator.

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) for `or` and `and` operators.

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching) for `on()` modifier.

Comment: Thanks!! It works. But I am facing another issue now... we have multiple regions in our environment so I have to check in each region and display the result. I tried the below query and it works fine when I select the specific location but when I select ALL it simply providing all instances (both canary and non-canary)
 (bound{cfstack=~".*Blue.*",location=${location} and on() (count by (location) (bound{cfstack=~".*Blue.*",location=${location}}) == 1)) or (bound{cfstack=~".*Green.*",location=${location}} and on() (count by (location) (bound{cfstack=~".*Green.*",location=${location}}) == 1))

Comment: Just add `location` label name into every `on()` modifier: `on(location)`. In this case Prometheus will match time series by `location` label values when performing `and` operation.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time!! Sorry to bother u again.. Adding one more panel to show CPU usage of canary 
((sum(rate(cpu_usage_total{cfstack=~".*Blue.*",location=~"${loc}"}[1m])) by (ip)) and on(loc) (count by (loc) (sum(rate(cpu_usage_total{cfstack=~".*Blue.*",location=~"${loc}"}[1m])) by (ip)) == 1)) or  ((sum(rate(cpu_usage_total{cfstack=~".*Green.*",location=~"${loc}"}[1m])) by (ip)) and on(loc) (count by (loc) (sum(rate(cpu_usage_total{cfstack=~".*Green.*",location=~"${loc}"}[1m])) by (ip)) == 1))
Same problem, it works fine with one location but when selecting as ALL it says no data

Comment: Substitute `on(loc)` with `on(location)` everywhere in the query. Please read https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#vector-matching